# Drag two overlapping shapes

Tags: drag-and-drop, kineticjs, overlap

I have two shapes that are overlapping, and I want to drag both when I click in the overlap. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Not the easiest, but simple, add them to a group and drag the group. You can get the intersecting shapes with .getIntersections(position). Then add the shapes to a group on click, then simulate dragstart.

Comment: can you put up a jsfiddle of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/JPeJF/1/

This is a little buggy, but you can spruce it up, it does what you ask for, just needs some more logic/polish.

The main code you need to look at is:

```
  shapesLayer.on('mousedown', function(){
     var userPos = stage.getUserPosition();
     var intersected = shapesLayer.getIntersections(userPos); //gets all shapes intersecting at click position
     for(var i = 0; i < intersected.length; i++) {
       intersected[i].moveTo(group2);   // moves intersected shapes to a new group , need to add some code so that when item is moved to new group it keeps it's position
     }
     group2.simulate('dragstart'); //simulate dragging
     shapesLayer.draw();
  });

  shapesLayer.on('mouseup', function(){  //when mouse is released
    var kids = group2.getChildren();
     for(var i = 0; i < kids.length; i++) {
       kids[i].moveTo(shapesLayer);      //place back in original container
     }
    shapesLayer.draw();
  });
```

Comment: I like it, but it's not working for me - getIntersections(pos) gets nothing. That said, if simulate('dragstart') causes a shape to start dragging, can I just call it on the shapes directly?

Comment: well, you cant use 'getIntersections(pos)' on nodes, only containers, but you can 'simulate(event)' on just about anything, so yes you can call it on the shapes directly. There are many different ways you can achieve what you want to do, I just tried creating a shortcut. The solution needs extra information on position so that you can drag the items you want.